# Edimax ew-7811un not operating at 5Ghz - Do I need to configure this?

Tags: wireless, networking

I'm using an edimax ew-7811un and I can connect to my 2.4Ghz access point however I can't seem to see my 5Ghz N-class access point. I was wondering if I needed to configure the pi to enable 5Ghz bandwidth?

My router is dual band and broadcasts 2 SSIDs (networkname-2G and networkname-5G), I also have my nexus 5 connected to the 5G SSID and working fine.

Output from running iwconfig:

IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"SOMESSID-2G"  Nickname:""
          Mode:Managed
Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: *someid*
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Edimax EW-7811UN does not work in 5GHz networks, it is only caable for 2.4GHz (see http://www.cnet.com/products/edimax-ew-7811un-network-adapter/specs/).

Comment: Ah, indeed! I got caught out by the 802.11n protocol rather than looking at the bandwidth

Comment: Please set then your issue as solved by this answer. Thanks!